# XSL template match returning unexpected data

Tags: xml, xslt

**When i apply bellow xslt:-**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//cd[year=2988]">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**to the bellow xml:**

```
    <catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>2988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

### **i am getting the following result:**

```
<html>
       <body>
          <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
          <table border="1">
             <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
                <td>Bob Dylan</td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </body>
    </html>
                Greatest Hits
        Dolly Parton
        USA
        RCA
        9.90
        1982
```

---

i am unable to understand why

```
    Greatest Hits
    Dolly Parton
    USA
    RCA
    9.90
    1982
```

is coming after the html tag ends.The template is applied and table is formed but why is the data again comming in the result
I am new to xslt .please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `<xsl:apply-templates/>` makes troubles... it is calling standard [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). Try to remove it.

Edit: For input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>2988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

The xslt should be following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//cd[year=2988]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
                <td>Bob Dylan</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: even after removing it .. i am getting the same result .

Comment: coud you please tell me how you are testing it ..i am using  http://xslttest.appspot.com/ for testing

Comment: I used Altova for that. I tried app on link you provided (btw, nice tool, i didn't know it) and it also worked correctly.

Comment: thanks a lot fot the responce ...can you please try this input <cd> repeating it is giving the above issue ------------------------------------------<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>2988</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Greatest Hits</title>
  <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>RCA</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1982</year>
 </cd>
</catalog>

Comment: Ah, I got it. I improved my answer.

Comment: that works !! thanks a lot .. just for my understanding .. <xsl:template match="/"> selects the entire xml and applies <xsl:template match="cd"> on top of it right ??? is that the way xslt works?? .. could you please tell me why extra lines where crreated wrongly earlier ??

Comment: No, `<xsl:template match="/">` is as template that matches the root of the input xml (not the root element). Built-in templates are used for nodes with no other template matching - simply put it outputs the string value of the node.